# Rails 4 not showing routes in 'rake routes' but views are working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake, ruby-on-rails-4

Pretty much as the title states, I have the following in my routes file:

```
  root to: 'assets#index'

  resources :assets do
    member do
      get :download
    end
  end
```

Yet my output for `rake routes` and visiting `rails/info/routes` are both simply:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
root GET / assets#index
```

However the routes work fine in my views.

I also tried with `bundle exec` and I've updated to the latest version of bundle as some other posts suggested. It still works for my Rails 3 apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:assets is a reserved path in Rails. So you cannot really use it.